# My Image is not removing from folder

Tags: php, mysql, unlink

I am trying to remove images from image folder and database. In my script it delete image from database but it is not removing from the image folder.

This is my CODE so far:

```
if ((isset($_POST['imageId'])) && (is_numeric($_POST['imageId'])) ) { // Form submission.
    $imageId = (int)$_POST['imageId'];

    // fetch the selected images to delete
    $query = " SELECT image_id, member_id, image
                         FROM  image_info
                         WHERE image_id = ?";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $imageId);  
        $stmt->execute();    
        $stmt->store_result();
        $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;

        if ($numrows == 1) {
            $stmt->bind_result($image_id, $member_id, $image);

            // define constant for upload folder
            //define('UPLOAD_DIR_2', "images/slider/$member_id");   

            // Fetch all the records:
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            if(file_exists("images/slider/$member_id/".$image)) {
                unlink("images/slider/$member_id/". $image); // delete file from folder
                //echo UPLOAD_DIR_2;
            } elseif(is_dir($image)) {
                rmdir($image); // or system("rm -rf " . escapeshellarg($dir)); 
            }
        }               

            // Make the delete query:
            $q = 'DELETE FROM image_info WHERE image_id= ? LIMIT 1'; 
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $imageId);

            // Execute the query:
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
                $success = "The slideshow image Deleted successfully.";
                echo $successAlert;
            }   
            $stmt->close();
            unset($stmt);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this? 
Hope somebody may help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have write permission in that folder (0777)?. if no then first change the permission of the folder and file and try it.

Comment: use path  unlink("/images/slider/$member_id/". $image);

Comment: @satishrajak, I tried it like you have mentioned. But its not working for me..

Comment: @RakeshSingh, How I change the permission?

Comment: use chmod function to change permission http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: take a look in the php log and/or apache error_log

Comment: @niyou. I can not see any error there relevant to this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try like this,

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/slider/".$member_id."/".$image;
unlink($path);
```

UPDATED:

```
$path = dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])."/images/slider/".$member_id."/".$image;
    unlink($path);
```

Comment: Hanky Panky, Now I can not get that error message. But Image is not removing from folder, but its deleting from db

Comment: print the path and check whether your path is correct or not

Comment: yes its seem fine - images/slider/16/16_tharanga_slideshow_banner_1.jpg

Comment: C:/wamp/www/_tutor-backend-develop/includes/images/slider/16/16_tharanga_slides‌​how_banner_1.jpg manually opens image in browser?

Comment: just do like this unlink("C:/wamp/www/_tutor-backend-develop/includes/images/slider/16/16_tharanga_slides‌​how_banner_1.jpg")

Comment: YEs... update my relative path with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
exec("chmod -R 777 $path/images/slider/$member_id/$image");
unlink("$path/images/slider/$member_id/$image");
```

Comment: No need for `exec()`.

Comment: I can get an error like this - An error occurred in script 'C:\wamp\www\_tutor-backend-develop\includes\process_delete_slideshow-image.php' on line 39: unlink(C:/wamp/www//images/slider/16/16_tharanga_slideshow_banner.jpg) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory

Comment: @satish If a webserver doesn't have permission to delete a file how can it have permission to change file permissions and then delete the file? What's the point then

Comment: `No such file or directory` means the file is just not there. Simple as that.

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).